# Type checking with dynamic class creation in Python

Tags: python, types

I want to create a class dynamically:

```py
from pydantic import BaseConfig

CompanyConfig: Type[BaseConfig] = type("CompanyConfig", (BaseConfig,), {})
```

Now, PyCharm 2022 complains `Expected type 'Type[BaseConfig]', got 'type' instead`. I can fix it by augmenting the type hint with "| type" or "| typing.Any":

```py
CompanyConfig: Type[BaseConfig] | type = type("CompanyConfig", (BaseConfig,), {})
```

This feels like a hack. Are there cleaner / more Pythonic solutions?

Comment: Type hints are for *static* type checking. Pycharm will parse a `class` statement to figure out what it produces, but it won't simulate an explicit call to `type` to figure out what *it* returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't receive a warning in Pycharm 2022.2.3 CE on macOS for below codes

```py
CompanyConfig: Type[int] = type("CompanyConfig", (int,), {})
```

but if you indeed met the mentioned problem, `typing.cast` might help

```py
from typing import (Type, cast)

CompanyConfig = cast(Type[int], type("CompanyConfig", (int,), {}))
```